# How mobile devices send information to telecom operators without using data network?

Tags: android, mobile, telecommunication, cellular-network

I came across a problem where the mobile device loses the data connectivity but the cellular network is available on the device. Does any one know with such connection, how mobile device sends information to its telecom operators? What are all the information device shares with the telecom operator and how? What architecture is followed by the telecom operators? Please share your knowledge.

Thanks in Advance,
Gaurav

Comment: I think you need to read few hundred pages of cellular connection specifications to answer this question...

Comment: Hi @VladMatvienko, can you share any link where I can go through and get the required information?

Comment: What do you mean by "*cellular network is available on the device*" ? Can you issue voice calls while no being able to do data or is it "just" that you see some bars ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the network type, e.g. 2G, 3G, LTE, CDMA etc, and the type of data, e.g. user or app level data, radio control data and information etc.

In very basic terms, on the data side there will be different protocol layers and even though the data transfer connectivity is not there at an IP later for example, i.e. allowing your an app or browser to communicate with the internet, there will most likely be control connectivity between the mobile device and the tower or network still available (to set up the data connection when resources are available, page the phone for calls etc).

Different network types have different standards and sets of protocols but 3GPP, which groups standards for 2G, 3G etc (or what we call 2G, 3G etc) is a good place to look, although you may want to search for '3GPP architecture overview' first to get some basic introductions.

This is a the place where the 3GPP architure spec is found:

- https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=821